# React setState inside setTimeout gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am writing a form that, when user completes input or time passes, saves the word to state, displays the word next to the form along previous words, and clears the form.
This is the function that triggers on every change of the form:

```
 function inputSearchTerm(e) {
    if (!searchTerms.includes(document.getElementById("site-search").value)) {
      let timeOutID = setTimeout(() => {
        let value = e.target.value;

        setSearchTerms([...searchTerms, value]);

        e.target.value = "";
      }, 1000);
      console.log(timeOutID)
    }
  }
```

This works fine on the first render, on the second render the value is lost from the state and is not displayed in the word list, and then it rerenders a third time, again with no value.

I have tried moving `let value = e.target.value;` outside of the `timeOut` like so:

```
 function inputSearchTerm(e) {
    let value = e.target.value;
    if (!searchTerms.includes(document.getElementById("site-search").value)) {
      let timeOutID = setTimeout(() => {
        setSearchTerms([...searchTerms, value]);

        e.target.value = "";
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

In that case, the search word appears next to the form after beign typed, but is rendered by the letter, which is not what I want.

I suspect my approach is very un-react here, but I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: The behavior you describe makes me think inputSearchTerm is running on each render, as opposed to only running when there is a change to the form field.  What if you add something to the event listener that only calls the function if e.target.value !== ''?

Comment: If you have multiple concurrent timeouts — which can easily happen, since you have no logic to cancel them — they'll stomp on each other, both by undoing each other's work (since each will capture its original `searchTerms`) and by clearing out the shared `e.target.value`. (Also: yes, this code seems very un-React to me, but it's hard to suggest how to fix it in isolation like this.)